# How to get a list of all of the block devices on a Linux system using OCaml's stdlib?

Tags: ocaml, block-device

I'm doing some fairly low level work with OCaml and need to get a list of all of the block-level files that exist on a given Linux machine. My current attempt involves running the following and then parsing based on `sd*` from there.

```ml
Sys.readdir "/dev/";;
```

But I am wondering if there is an existing/better way to do this? Since block devices have a ton of different names I'll have to write a ton of regexp. Is there a  way that would let me specify that I only want block device files?

**Note**: Unfortunately I am unable to use Jane Street Core, or any other libraries for this.

Comment: in theory, device files can appear anywhere. They don't have to be in the `/dev` directory (though they almost always are there). Do you want to access every bock device anywhere on the system? Do you want to treat partitions as separate devices?

Comment: See also https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux/lsblk.8.en.html

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I'd like to find all of the devices in `/dev`, though a solution that would work for any directory would be excellent as well. I think @Chris solution is about what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Unix` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Unix.html) has a function `Unix.stat` which returns a record of type `Unix.stats` describing a file. The `st_kind` field is of type `Unix.file_kind` which has a constructor `S_BLK` if a device is a block level device.

So, you could write something like the following to get a list of block level devices without relying on the filenames themselves to make that determination.

```
let dir = "/dev" in
dir 
|> Sys.readdir  
|> Array.to_seq
|> Seq.map (fun fn -> dir ^ "/" ^ fn)
|> Seq.filter (fun fn -> Unix.((stat fn).st_kind = S_BLK))
|> List.of_seq
```

This could be wrapped up into a function to allow easily reading block devices from any directory.

```
let block_devices_in_dir dir =
  dir 
  |> Sys.readdir  
  |> Array.to_seq
  |> Seq.map (fun fn -> dir ^ "/" ^ fn)
  |> Seq.filter (fun fn -> Unix.((stat fn).st_kind = S_BLK))
  |> List.of_seq
```